# Setup for “widget” administration module (generic vs specific)

Tags: c#, architecture, frontend, backend

I have sort of an architecture question.

I have a type, let’s call it Widget. There a many subtypes of this class such as Grid, doughnut, graph etc. The idea is that these will represent the models for what is shown on an Dashboard as you see in most enterprise systems.

Now what I need to do, is create a module for the people that create these widgets. So eg. I need a frontend with forms for creating these different types of widgets (ie. The grid widget will need some column names, the graph will need some x and y-axis fields and so on). Each of the widgets will in the backend have a “build” method that generates the actual widget with the arguments specified by the user.

Instead of creating individual forms for each of these widgets I thought I could perhaps just return a list of fields for each widget type and have a generic form that fetches said list depending on what type of widget the user creates. Only my issue is that having this will also result in the backend data being unstructured and my “build” methods on my widget subclasses not being strongly typed with regards to the arguments provided by the user.

Ie. If I have individual forms and storage per widget, my build method will know exactly which fields are accessible (like graphwidget.x and graphwidget.y) as opposed to having to search the dataobject for those properties (like graphwidget.fields.tryget(“x”) and graphwidget.fields.tryget(“y”)).

What kind of solution do I need?